# rotate lines of text in a variable

Tags: string, powershell, variables, rotation

I have a a string variable with lines of serial numbers, I need to rotate the serial numbers in the variable and then output that to the screen.
Basically move the first serial to the end and delete it from the beginning.
I'm able to move the first serial to the end of the variable but cannot figure out how to remove it from the beginning .

example

```
$serials = "6546544`n6542185`n6546848`n6654898`n6522828"
#append first serial number to the end
$serials +="`n$($serials.split()[0])" 
#remove the first serial from beginning.????
```

End result should be:

```
"6542185`n6546848`n6654898`n6522828`n6546544"
```

Comment: Just curious. Why are you doing this 
  ["6546544`n6542185`n6546848`n6654898`n6522828"]  vs   just ['6546544','6542185', '6546848', '6654898', '6522828']? The latter is and array/collection by default, then you just use normal array add/remove or coolection add/remove methods and the like. You could have also done this with that $serials variable. [$serials = '6546544 6542185 6546848 6654898 6522828' -split(' ')]

Comment: Because i'm not creating this input it is being fetched from somewhere else. And when sending the output back it has to be in the same format.

Comment: Understood, but having formatting characters to force this into an array layout vs using natural array had me scratching my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$serials = "6546544`n6542185`n6546848`n6654898`n6522828"
#append first serial number to the end
$first = ($serials.Split()[0]).trim()
$serials = ($serials -replace $first).trim()
$serials += "`n$($first)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to work with a collection, a queue object inherently has this functionality:

```
$serials = "6546544`n6542185`n6546848`n6654898`n6522828"
# Create queue object with entries for each serial
$queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::new(-split $serials)

# Dequeues the top item and enqueues the item to the bottom
$queue.Enqueue($queue.Dequeue())

# Create string joined by newline character
$serials = $queue -join "`n"

# Optionally output a list and skip the string join above
$queue
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$serials = "6546544`n6542185`n6546848`n6654898`n6522828"
$test = @()
$test = $serials.split()
$final = @()

for($i = 1; $i -lt  $test.count; $i++){

    $final += $test[$i]

}

$final += $test[0]
$final
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending this idea from my comment (no splitting required).

Example:

```
Clear-Host
Write-Verbose -Message "Current array" -Verbose
($serials = '6546544','6542185', '6546848', '6654898', '6522828')
"`n"
#append first serial number to the end
Write-Verbose -Message "Modified array" -Verbose
($serials += $($serials[0]))
"`n"
Write-Verbose -Message "Final array" -Verbose
($serials = ($serials | Select -Skip 1))
# Results
<#
VERBOSE: Current array
6546544
6542185
6546848
6654898
6522828


VERBOSE: Modified array
6546544
6542185
6546848
6654898
6522828
6546544


VERBOSE: Final array
6542185
6546848
6654898
6522828
6546544
#>
```

.. then join back in whatever way you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to split the serials into an array, and recombine that array with the first element appended to the end:

```
# split on "`n" to get an array
$serials = "6546544`n6542185`n6546848`n6654898`n6522828" -split "`n"
# recombine the array in different order with "`n"
$serials = ($serials[1..($serials.Count - 1)] + $serials[0]) -join "`n"
```

`$serials` now contains `` "6542185`n6546848`n6654898`n6522828`n6546544" ``